# Does the level/reading/measurement of solar exposure impact temperatures

Tags: temperature, measurements

Does the level/reading/measurement of solar exposure impact temperatures? What I mean by this is, does a higher level/reading/measurement of solar exposure of a place cause/create higher temperatures, and does a lower level/reading/measurement of solar exposure of a place cause/create lower temperatures?

Comment: Generally speaking yes, as you would expect. However, I presume the relative amount of heating of the site in question would depend upon its' albedo, and whether the cloud cover reflects the heat back to Earth that would otherwise be re-radiated back into space.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but temperatures are properly measured in the shade. If you're standing/measuring in direct sunlight you are constantly receiving radiation from the sun, which would make measurements inaccurate (at some point, you'd reach an equilibrium temperature, but I don't think there are thermometers designed to measure that)